# Assign values from one set of key/value pairs to keys of another?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working with the outputs of an Intranet I don't control.

I have this string:

```
let template = 'LAWYER=|FIRM=|SUIT_DESCRIPTION=|DEF_COMMENT=|PLF_COMMENT=|';
```

It goes on longer, but that's the pattern.

Now there's another similar string, but with data assigned, as in this example:

```
let current= 'FIRM=Smith and Wesson LLP|SUIT_DESCRIPTION=It\'s a royal mess|PLF_COMMENT=some freeform text|LAWYER=Bob Smith';
```

Now, notice that not every element in *template* is necessarily represented in *current*, and the order may be different (if the latter fact is a big deal, I can ensure the order is the same).

What I'm trying to do, is take every element that is in *current*, and populate the matching element in *template*, if it exists. (or, alternatively and potentially preferred, insert every non-matching element in *template* into *current*, but ideally in the same order as *template*).

Using the date above, the result I'm looking for is:

```
result = 'LAWYER=Bob Smith|FIRM=Smith and Wesson LLP|SUIT_DESCRIPTION=It\'s a royal mess|DEF_COMMENT=|PLF_COMMENT=some freeform text|';
```

I'm not very accomplished with JavaScript :(

I tried various things in JSFiddle using split() and match() but I just made a mess of it.

Comment: Programming questions should be asked on Stackoverflow. I've flagged your question for migration.

Comment: Shoot... I knew that.  Just a mental moment, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Convert the template to an array of keys
const getKeys = str => str.split('|').map(entry => entry.split('=')[0]);

// Convert the data to an object
const toObj = str => Object.fromEntries(str.split('|').map(entry => entry.split('=')));

// Reconcile the data with the template
const compile = (templateStr, dataStr) => {
  const keys = getKeys(templateStr);
  const data = toObj(dataStr);
  return keys.reduce((results, key) => {
    if(key) results.push([key, data[key] ?? '']);
    return results;
  }, []);
};

// Convert the results back into a string
const toString = data => data.map(entry => entry.join('=')).join('|') + '|';

// And then a test
let template = 'LAWYER=|FIRM=|SUIT_DESCRIPTION=|DEF_COMMENT=|PLF_COMMENT=|';
let current = 'FIRM=Smith and Wesson LLP|SUIT_DESCRIPTION=It\'s a royal mess|PLF_COMMENT=some freeform text|LAWYER=Bob Smith';

console.log(toString(compile(template, current)));
```

Comment: Wow.  That is not something I would have come up with if given a year!  Thank you